# Struct inheritance or workaround

Tags: struct, inheritance

I've got a quite complex contract with two arrays:

```
struct TransactionsLink {
    uint transactionId;
    uint creationTime;
    uint amount;
}

mapping( address => TransactionsLink[]) public transactionsFinder;


struct BillLink {
    uint billId;
    uint creationTime;
    string name;
}   
mapping( address => ResearchBillLink[]) public billsFinder;


function getBillsIndexBetweenTimes(uint _startTimestamp, uint _endTimestamp) constant returns(uint startIdx, uint endIdx){ if (billsFinder[0].creationTime) .... }
function getTransactionIndexBetweenTimes(uint _startTimestamp, uint _endTimestamp) constant returns(uint startIdx, uint endIdx){ if (transactionsFinder[0].creationTime) .... }
```

And I've developed a binary search algorithm inside the contract in order to get bills/transactions for someone from those arrays. However my code is quite big (range search) and I would like to reuse it for both arrays (in fact I've got 4).

Is there a way in which I can reuse my function without pasting all the code twice?

```
function getArrIndexesBetweenTimes(GenericStruct[] arr, uint _startTimestamp, uint _endTimestamp) constant returns(uint startIdx, uint endIdx){ if (transactionsFinder[0].creationTime) .... }
function getBillsIndexBetweenTimes(uint _startTimestamp, uint _endTimestamp) constant returns(uint startIdx, uint endIdx){return getArrIndexesBetweenTimes(billsFinder)}
function getTransactionIndexBetweenTimes(uint _startTimestamp, uint _endTimestamp) constant returns(uint startIdx, uint endIdx){ return getArrIndexesBetweenTimes(transactionsFinder) }
```

I would like to be able to do the second, but structs do not seems to support inheritance, I could try playing with how structs are mapped in memory and placing creationTime as first parameter, but I'm not sure that would be totally safe...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

*I came to a temporary workaround not to duplicate a too much code, however any other suggestion would be great because its quite dirty and non-scalable :)

```
function getCreationTime(uint arrayType) private returns (uint ret) {
    if (arrayType==BFINDER_CONST) {
            ret=billsFinder[clientAddr].length;
    } else if (arrayType==TFINDER_CONST) {
            ret=transactionsFinder[clientAddr].length;
    }
    return ret;
}
```